# PAYTM payment integration with angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I am trying to embed and integrate Paytm in my angular application. I have followed all the steps mention in the Paytm docs. But somehow Paytm variable is not generate in windows event.
I have embedded the script in index.html file and trying to access in my components.
Don't know what wrong I have done..same thing is working with RazorPay.

Thanks

Comment: I am also trying it, can you pass on the document link or what code you are trying?